# Show E-Mail content on .jsp page / GAE

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am writing an application with Google App Engine.
The app can receiver eMails now and I can see these in the console.

What I want is that the three variables (summary, addresses and text) are visible in the frontend (guestbook.jsp).
I tried to various options (see commented code) but none of them showed me the information in the frontend.
By now I only tried to pass one variable (summary).

Later on I want to store the information in a database.

Servlet:

```
package com.example.mail;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.servlet.http.*; 
import javax.mail.Address;

public class MailHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet { 
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws IOException { 
                Properties props = new Properties(); 
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 

            try{    
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());
                String summary = message.getSubject();
                Address[] addresses = message.getFrom();
                String text = message.getContent().toString();
                System.out.println("Subject: " + summary);
                System.out.println("Sender: " + addresses);
                System.out.println("Text: " + text);  

                req.setAttribute("summary",summary);
                req.getRequestDispatcher("/mail.jsp").forward(req, resp); 


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

mail.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>

Hello World!

<p>E-Mail Summary '${summary}'.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.mail.MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/string@appid.appspotmail.com</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: I now get the following error if I send a local testmail: Message send failure Error 404 /_ah/mail/mail.jsp - this seems to do with the web.xml but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `request.setAttribute("summary", summary);` to add summary as a request attribute, and since a redirect isnt server side, it's client side, the attributes are no longer shown, you'll need to use `req.getRequestDispatcher("mail.jsp").forward(req, resp);`

Comment: Hey Zack, I updated the code in the Servlet. But when I send a Mail to my program I can still only see the variable values in the console, but the summary value is not displayed in mail.jsp. I also added a / in the dispatcher, so ("/mail.jsp") because without it I received an error.

Comment: Change your mail.jsp to `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>

Hello World!

<p>E-Mail Summary '${summary}'.</p>

</body>`

Comment: Before you were setting a variable called summary to null by trying to get a request **parameter**, a parameter is set by the **client**, a request **attribute** is set server side.

Comment: Hey Zack, I changed the mail.jsp and updated the code, but still if I send an eMail to the address I do not see the text, still I can only see it in the terminal...